# Python File Output, Looping, and Increasing

Tags: python, file, output

```
number = 1
name = 'Frames' + str(number) + '.html'
usedNumbers = []
if number in usedNumbers:
    number += 1
else:
    open(name,'w')
```

How would I go about doing this where 'number' increases by 1, puts out the html document, until it gets to 18, then stops before it gets to 19?
("Frames1.html. Frames2.html, ..., Frames18.html")

Comment: Not clear what you are asking, and please put the code in text, one can't just copy paste and test it for you if its  PICTURE.

Comment: show was what you have tried too

Answer (score 3):

Just use a for loop, like:

```
for number in range(1,20):
    # the rest of the stuff.
```

Resources on [for loops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop) and [range](http://pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/).

Comment: I have this working, but it does't output all the files. (Here's a gif of what's happening: [gif](https://gyazo.com/bf55173c8c61e450e14b27b9c75f8576)

Comment: You use other code. You don't use a `for` loop at all. You're just checking whether `number` is in the range.

Comment: DecapitatedRainbow you're almost there, you just need the maximum of your range to be one higher. I'd suggest reading the resources on range to figure out how to do that.
@Matthias what do you mean..? Post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

```python
for i in range(1, 19):
    if i in usedNumbers:
        pass
    else:
        open(name, "w")
```